# Apply Criteria to Editable Column Read From SQL Server Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My aim is to have an editable table for the end user but editing will be limited to a few different values, a drop-down list.

Currently I have this code which does almost what I want, but creates a new column, rather than applying the criteria to an existing one.

```
var data = new List<ValueHolder>();
            data.Add(new ValueHolder("EMPTY"));
            data.Add(new ValueHolder("FULL"));
            ////..................

            var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            column.DataSource = data;
            column.ValueMember = "Name";
            column.DisplayMember = "Name";

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

I've tried to apply to an existing column which I'm already reading in, but I can't quite get the correct syntax and haven't been able to turn it up via web searching. Any pointer would be great.

**EDIT**

To make myself more clear;

I have a C# table - generated from a sql server table.

I want the data to be editable by drop down menu, e.g.

```
var data = new List<ValueHolder>();
        data.Add(new ValueHolder("EMPTY"));
        data.Add(new ValueHolder("FULL"));
```

How would I apply this list criteria to the columns in my table?